# Images won't display in the Colorbox when I click on the link; they just open in a new window/tab

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am a new user to color box in JQuery. And I have been try to get the sample code to work on my computer and the images won't display in the 'colorbox', when I click on the link they just open in a new window/tab. So I will show you my code. And I need help with things that may be obvious to you because I'm a beginner. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

 <link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

</head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<body>
<!--JQuery library-->
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      var foo = "bar";
    </script>


<!--Colorbox Call-->



    <a class='gallery' href='images/DSC_0114.JPG'>Photo_1</a>
        <a class='gallery'     href='images/34180_1473822933002_1456544245_1218149_7765685_n.jpg'>Photo_2</a>
        <a class='gallery'     href='images/26577_1337288319722_1456544245_897498_8319969_n.jpg'>Photo_3</a>

        <script>
            jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox();
        </script>

</body>



<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="box" id="box">Content for  class "box" id "box" Goes Here</div>
```

These are the sites that I'm using for help but they don't answer the really small questions.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide
http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Do I need to upload the site to the web to make the color box work?

Answer (score 0):

You've appended `jquery.js` second time, I think that is breaking the code `jquery.colorbox-min.js`, so that doesn't work. Remove the second one.

you should remove this line,

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5bwx3/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
</head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<body>
    <a class='gallery' href='images/DSC_0114.JPG'>Photo_1</a>
    <a class='gallery' href='images/34180_1473822933002_1456544245_1218149_7765685_n.jpg'>Photo_2</a>
    <a class='gallery' href='images/26577_1337288319722_1456544245_897498_8319969_n.jpg'>Photo_3</a>

    <script>
        jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox();
    </script>

    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <div class="box" id="box">Content for  class "box" id "box" Goes Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE:

Here is the latest code that you shared,

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="Colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="Colorbox/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head> 
<title></title> 
<a class='gallery' href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_1</a> 
<a class='gallery' href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_2</a> 
<a class='gallery' href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_3</a> 
<script> jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox(); }); </script>
```

There must be these files in `Colorbox` folder,

- jquery.min.js
- jquery.colorbox-min.js

Comment: Thanks Ocanal, but could you be a little more specific? If you are talking about leaving <script src="query.min.js"></script> and taking away <script src="query.colorbox-min.js"></script> that didn't work. So maybe I don't know where to take out code.

Comment: you should remove only `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Okay, I removed "<script src="jquery.js"></script>" and it still didn't work. The images opened in a new browser window.

Comment: Are you sure about you have `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.colorbox-min.js` files on the same folder with your example html page? Have you checked console, what error are you getting?

Comment: Okay, it worked for a second, and then I did something with out realizing it, and it doesn't work again. Ocanal, linking the files is what finally got it to work. But after that, it won't work again. I think I did something dumb. I'm sure one more snippet of help will cure my Colorbox problem.

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<title></title>
<a class='gallery' href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_1</a>
<a class='gallery' href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_2</a>
<a class='gallery' href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_3</a>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox();
});
</script>

Comment: that is my code now. I took out the body tags and the spaces so I could post it. But that makes it really hard to read, so sorry about that.

Comment: `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` is missed, look my updated answer again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22860/discussion-between-ocanal-and-emily-magnuson)